# rqt_reconfigure window is totally empty

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

rqt_reconfigure looks working badly on my computer. It shows a totally empty window. It is showing no parameter, no grid, and no command window. Nothing. 
I was trying to reconfigure the parameter of the pointgray camera. Cutting off Auto exposure and Turn on the Trigger.
I tried troubleshooting in the rqt_reconfigure wiki but it seems there is no problem. There are some return by hitting
"$ rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam list".
Below is a screenshot of troubleshooting(left) and rqt_reconfigure window(right).
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thank you in advance.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325724/rqt_reconfigure-window-is-totally-empty/) by [yoshiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/36541/yoshiros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-06-13**:
Please provide more information. What OS are you using? How did you install ROS? See the [support guide](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your comment Geoff. The problem is solved.
When I right click at the empty window, the option appeared. (Forgot to screenshot and never appear again). After that, a small "dynamic reconfigure" button appeared. All windows came up with pushing the button.

---

Originally posted by [yoshiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/36541/yoshiros/) with karma: 69 on 2019-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is an issue on rqt_reconfigure itself, see: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_reconfigure/issues/4

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2020-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1